# Where does the Callback object come from in the ListenableWorker example?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

The [Android developer docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/listenableworker.html) show an example of how to use a ListenableWorker. However, despite having added `councurrent-futures` to my project, I see now relevant Callback object as used in the docs:

```
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork() {
        return CallbackToFutureAdapter.getFuture(completer -> {
            Callback callback = new Callback() {
            ...
            }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? There doesnt seem to be a `Callback` class in `androidx.concurrent.callback` at all.

[this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/camera/core/src/main/java/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture.java) is literally the only code sample I can find that uses `CallbackToFutureAdapter.getFuture` at all.

Comment: You have one in your code already. If you don't, you don't need a callback-to-future-adapter. The trick here is that you can use code that you call like `downloadAsynchronously("https://www.google.com", callback)` with whatever callback that code wants and still turn it into a future so that you can wait on the completion of that download in this example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking at the documentation to a similar API, it looks to me that *Callback*
is not an API in itself but a generic representation of any operation with results.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/concurrent/futures/CallbackToFutureAdapter.html

As an example, you could define the callback as follows,

```
interface AsyncCallback  {
   void onSuccess(Foo foo);
   void onError(Failure failure);
}
```

And the startWork method as follows

```
@Override
public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork() {
    return CallbackToFutureAdapter.getFuture(completer -> {
        AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback() {
            int successes = 0;

            @Override
            public void onError(Failure failure) {
                completer.setException(failure.getException());
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Foo foo) {
                completer.set(Result.success());
            }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            downloadAsynchronously("https://www.google.com", callback);
        }
        return callback;
    });
}
```